# Como adicionar variável a um seletor do Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, fiz um método em Javascript que ao clicar em um botão é adicionado um texto com efeito toggle. Só que eu estou utilizando uma função que recebe 2 valores como argumentos pra fazer isso, e eu não consigo utilizar esses argumentos nos seletores do jquery.

```js
function adicionaToggle(btnId, pId) {
  $('#btnId').click(function() {
    $('#pId').toggle();
  });
  console.log(btnId, pId);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').hide();
  $('button').click(function() {
    var btnId = $(this).attr('id');
    var pId = $('button').siblings('p').attr('id');
    adicionaToggle(btnId, pId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1">
  <img src="espaco.jpg" width="300" height="200">
  <p id="info1">Blabla</p>
  <button id="btn">Mais informações</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara acho que você se perdeu um pouco nos atributos dos elementos na hora de fazer o código, e fez confusão. **Você no clique do botão chama uma função que também tem o mesmo evento de clique do mesmo botão** o que é desnecessário, aliás a função **`adicionaToggle()`** é totalmente desnecessária, você pode fazer o **toggle()** no click do botão mesmo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#info1').hide();
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#info1').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1">
  <img src="espaco.jpg" width="300" height="200">
  <p id="info1">Blabla</p>
  <button id="btn">Mais informações</button>
</div>
```

Mas se mesmo assim quiser manter esta função **`adicionaToggle()`** pode deixá-la assim:

```js
function adicionaToggle(btnId, pId) {
  $('#info1').toggle();
  console.log(btnId, pId);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#info1').hide();
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    var btnId = $(this).attr('id');
    var pId = $('button').siblings('p').attr('id');
    adicionaToggle(btnId, pId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1">
  <img src="espaco.jpg" width="300" height="200">
  <p id="info1">Blabla</p>
  <button id="btn">Mais informações</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite, não esqueça que o jquery $() é um seletor, você esta capturando o ID dos elementos:

`var btnId = $(this).attr('id');
var pId = $('button').siblings('p').attr('id');`

**btn e info1**
ou seja você esta esquecendo de colocar **#** no seletor!

pode-se colocar assim se quiser:

```
adicionaToggle('#'+btnId,'#'+pId);
```

outra você não esta utilizando as variáveis que está passando para função!

```
        function adicionaToggle(btnId,pId){     
            $(btnId).click(function(){
                $(pId).toggle();
            });
            $(pId).toggle(); // COLOQUE ISSO PARA O TOGGLE OCORRER NO PRIMEIRO CLICK
            console.log(btnId,pId);
        }
```

Não entendi o porque de fazer uma função para adicionar o toggle, veja se sua ideia esta correta.
Para mais efeitos do toggle de uma olhada -> https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp

```
$(selector).toggle(speed,easing,callback);
```